# setup.py distutils test location

Tags: python, nose

In a setup.py, the package_dir map has the convenient effect of mapping packages to file system locations.

Now, what's the story with tests? Is 'tests' just the name of a package, and I can map it like any other? Or is there something more complex about tests are collected. I'm using nosetests.

So far, setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='ws-client-binding',
      version='0.1-SNAPSHOT',
      packages=['rosette', 'rosette.generated'],
      package_dir={
        'rosette': '../rosette',
        'rosette.generated': '/Users/benson/x/ws-client-bindings/python/setup/target/generated-python/generated'
      },
      requires=["requests (>= 0.14.0)"],
      setup_requires=['nose>=1.0']
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, this was an easy one. In setup.cfg,

```
[nosetests]
test=../tests
```

specifies the location.